# Scipy minimize - minimum absolute weights but 0 acceptable

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to optimize a portfolio allocation.
I am happy for some weights to be 0 but I do not want to get values that are less than some threshold  T. this is on absolute values as negative weights are accepted.

So something like W = [w0, w1, ..., wn] where abs(wi) >= T or 0.

Is that at all possible?

I have not been able to find out.
My 2 options at the moment:

- remove any abs(wi) < T (so I enforce 0) and re-optimize
- or is there a more appropriate optimiser tool?

Thanks,

looked all around the place. I am starting to implement the remove small weights and re-run method but I feel there should be a better way.

Edit:
I will add more code tomorrow but basically I have a really simple
A * x = B equation to solve.
A is an upper diagonal matrix and B a vector.
So if it was not for my constraint on weight, this is a simple matrix inversion and you get a perfect match.
This will quite often come up with weights that are too small for our liking, so we want to force the optimiser to set 0s for those weights under a certain threshold.
The cost function is a standard quadratic error.

Edit 2:
Here is the code:

```
class TestMinimizer:
    def __init__(self, X, target, min_size=None):
        self.X = X
        self.target = target
        self.min_size = min_size

    def solve(self) -> pd.Series:
        w0 = np.ones_like(self.target)

        solution = minimize(self.objective_function, w0, bounds=None)
        return solution.x

    def objective_function(self, weights):
        error = np.matmul(self.X, weights) - self.target
        return (error**2).sum()
```

Again, I would like to use the min_size to force individual weight in that weights vector to be more than min_size in absolute values or 0s. So the constraint is not continuous.

Am I making any sense?

Comment: Probably possible, but there is not enough information here. You need to show exactly what your objective is, along with all variables, bounds and weights.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just be able to do:

```
    def objective_function(self, weights):
        # set values below min_size theshold to zero
        weights[np.abs(weights) < self.min_size] = 0.0
        error = np.matmul(self.X, weights) - self.target
        return (error**2).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks! really simple. I did not think about adding it into the objective function. Definitely something I'll keep in mind. "obviously" need to apply the same filter on weights after the optimisation.

Comment: Of course, when you use the final weights that get returned, you'll also need to set the below threshold values to zero as well.

Comment: thanks again. You seem to have had a notification once I replied. Would you mind to tell me how do I set them up? I was not receiving any for replies on my own topic and cant figure that one out...

Comment: I don't think I did anything in particular to get notifications turned on as far as I recall. But, in your profile you could click on the "Settings" and see if in the "Edit email settings" -> "Your communities" if you have "Inbox" set to "Off" or not.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. it is set to every 3h, maybe I checked the topic before it got sent. I assume you could receive an email after every comment on some topics as you answered so quickly but the minimum seems to be 3h. Best regards,

Comment: I don't get email notifications for comments though - I just happened to be on StackOverflow and saw a notification flag in my SO inbox then.